# How to override spring cloud property with local property

Tags: spring

Simple yml that stored in cloud

```
something:
 that: not be overriding
cache:
 size: 1000
 duration: 3
```

this property using in config java class

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "cache")
public class CachingConfig extends CachingConfigurerSupport {

    private int duration;
    private int maxSize;
```

i want to write some integration test and i need to override these properties cache.duration and cache.maxSize with local value that stored in test/resources/application-test.yml

ps.I need to override only these ones, not all properties that was stored in cloud, it means i do not want to override something:

is there any way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming your question is in the context of a `SpringBootTest`. If that is the case you have two ways of doing this:

1. Either you annotate your test class with `@ActiveProfiles("test")` in which case it will use the `cache.size` and `cache.duration` you specify in `application-test.yml` or
2. You annotate your test class with `@TestPropertySource` as below:

   ```
   @TestPropertySource(properties = {
       "cache.size=20",
       "cache.duration=5"
   })
   @SpringBootTest
   class MyTestClass {
    ....
   }
   ```

You can use both together as well and the values specified via `@TestPropertySource` taking precedence.

Comment: Not sure what cloud has to do with this, You are running integration tests part of a CI pipeline. Profile is a very basic technique of overriding properties from application.yml with the one you need for testing. We run our apps in AWS and this is how we test

Comment: yea thnx Julian, @TestPropertySource works good

Comment: All good but sorry to say so there is no place for `f` word on a professional site like this. The reason I insisted about the profile approach was because I misread your question and did not realize you were accessing a config server from your integration tests. Arguably a good idea. I would rather run this type of all connected tests part regression BDD suite rather than part of CI. But again, I might not even understand your setup. In our CI builds when we run integration tests we fire up a docker compose and drive all the test config from inside an yml file.